# Setting UIScrollView's contentInset for keyboardWillShowNotification not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikeyboard

I have a ViewController with the following structure (`(x)` indicating the level):

```
UIViewController    (1)
  - NavigationBar   (2)
  - UIScrollView    (2)
    - UIView        (3)
      - UITextField (4)
      - UITextField (4)
      - UITextField (4)
      - UITextField (4)
      - UIButton    (4)
```

- All elements of level `4` are vertically constrained to eachother with a spacing of 16.
- The first and last elements of level `4` are constrained to the UIView's (`3`) top and bottom.
- The UIView (`3`) is constrained with top and bottom to the UIScrollView (`2`).
- The UIScrollView (`2`) is constrained to the NavigationBar's bottom (`2`) and the superview's bottom (`1`)
- (Of course there are the necessary horizontal constraints as well!)

The UIView (`3`) has the following constraints:

- Leading constraint of 0 to all subViews.
- Trailing constraint of 0 to all subviews.
- Bottom space of 24 to UIButton (should add *some* extra spacing)
- Top space of 24 to the topmost UITextField (top spacing)
- Top space of 0 to superView (UIScrollView)
- Bottom space of 0 to superView (UIScrollView)
- 'Equal width - minus 32' to NavigationBar (so — fixed width)

In the `viewDidLoad` of the viewController, I call this:

```swift
registerForKeyboardWillShowNotification(self.scrollView)
registerForKeyboardWillHideNotification(self.scrollView)
```

Where `registerForKeyboard...ShowNotification` is an extension of `UIViewController`:

```swift
extension UIViewController
{
    /// Act when keyboard is shown, by adding contentInsets to the scrollView.
    func registerForKeyboardWillShowNotification(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, usingBlock block: ((CGSize?) -> Void)? = nil)
    {
        _ = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
                                                   object: nil, queue: nil)
        { notification in
            let userInfo      = notification.userInfo!
            let keyboardSize  = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size
            let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: scrollView.contentInset.top,
                                             left: scrollView.contentInset.left,
                                             bottom: keyboardSize.height,
                                             right: scrollView.contentInset.right)

            scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
            block?(keyboardSize)
        }
    }

    /// Act when keyboard is hidden, by removing contentInsets from the scrollView.
    func registerForKeyboardWillHideNotification(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, usingBlock block: ((CGSize?) -> Void)? = nil)
    {
        _ = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
                                                   object: nil, queue: nil)
        { notification in
            let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
            let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size
            let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: scrollView.contentInset.top,
                                             left: scrollView.contentInset.left,
                                             bottom: 0,
                                             right: scrollView.contentInset.right)

            scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
            block?(keyboardSize)
        }
    }
}
```

However, when the keyboard shows, it doesn't inset the scrollView (enough). I debugged, and this is the case:

- Regular keyboard: `height = 216`
- Regular keyboard with suggestion bar: `height = 260`
- iPhone X keyboard with suggestion bar: `height = 291`

I first though the suggestion bar could be the problem, but it's not.

In `registerForKeyboardWillShowNotification` I changed `bottom: keyboardSize.height` to `bottom: keyboardSize.height + 30`, which gives exactly the same result (I see the same part of the button that's partially hidden behind the keyboard). Once I add 50 or more, it finally seems to make a small difference.

- Instead of `keyboardWillShowNotification` I tried `keyboardDidShowNotification`, this doesn't make a difference.
- Instead of `keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` I tried `keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`, this doesn't make a difference.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what are your UIView constraints?

Comment: I edited the question and added the UIView constraints.

Comment: what about UIView height?

Comment: That's derived from it's contents (TextFields / Button). Since it has a top and bottom constraint of 24 to those.

Comment: add height with priority 750, change hugging priority to 1000

Comment: Why add a height too UIView?

Comment: because scrollview doesn't know about its content size, you can try do same without UIView as a container and it will works

Comment: Okay, I gave it a try. Unfortunately it doesn't change anything.
Also, scrollView _should_ know it's contentSize, since the UIView get it's size from the subViews, while the UIView is constrained to the scrollView. Also, I inspected the view hierarchy -> the scrollView seems to have just the right size for its content.
However, like you're also thinking, there seems to be something wrong with the scrollView's size indeed.

Comment: Just to try, I removed the UIView and added the 5 views to UIScrollView directly. Unfortunately with the same result!

Comment: I also had some NSLayoutConstraint errors, but I went through those, and they are not the problem in this.

Comment: resolve constraint errors firstly, I think this is the main problem

Comment: Yes, that's fixed now, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I haven't been able to solve this, I'm unsure why this doesn't work as expected.

However, I got the expected behaviour by using a UIStackView inside the UIScrollView. I used [this article](https://blog.alltheflow.com/scrollable-uistackview/) as reference.

---

**The UI layout**

- UIViewController  (1)

  - NavigationBar   (2)
  - UIScrollView    (2)
  - UIStackView   (3)

    - UITextField (4)
    - UITextField (4)
    - UITextField (4)
    - UITextField (4)
    - UIButton    (4)

---

**The `UIScrollView`**

- ScrollView's `leading` and `trailing` are constrained with **16** to the superView.
- ScrollView's `top` is constrained with **0** to the navigationBar's bottom.
- ScrollView's `bottom` is constrained with **0** to the superView's bottom.

---

**The `UIStackView`**

- StackView's `leading` and `trailing` are constrained with **0** to the scrollView.
- StackView has an equal width to scrollView.
- StackView's `top` and `bottom` are constrained with **24** to the scrollView, to get the desired spacing to the navigationBar, and between the button and the keyboard.
- StackView is setup as `axis=vertical`, `alignment=fill`, `distribution=fill`, `spacing=24`.

---

**The NavigationBar**

The NavigationBar is a custom class that derives its height from its contents. This didn't have a height constraint set, but a placeholder height of 100. The NavigationBar would fill the entire screen. This is solved by removing the placeholder height, and adding *any* height constraint with a low priority (in this case a priority of `1`).

---

The initial code for applying the keyboard inset works now.

```
/// Act when keyboard is shown, by adding contentInsets to the scrollView.
func registerForKeyboardWillShowNotification(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, usingBlock block: ((CGSize?) -> Void)? = nil)
{
    _ = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
                                               object: nil, queue: nil)
    { notification in
        let userInfo      = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardSize  = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: scrollView.contentInset.top,
                                         left: scrollView.contentInset.left,
                                         bottom: keyboardSize.height,
                                         right: scrollView.contentInset.right)

        scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        block?(keyboardSize)
    }
}
```